# ping tool that measures in micro seconds

Tags: home-networking

When I do a ping on my pc to my router it says it's <1ms which is great. However what if you wanted greater resolution i.e. microseconds. How would you do this using software?

I've never used an expensive professional network tester with ping facility. Because they're so expensive I can only assume they can measure down to Microseconds?

Apologies if this is pointless but just curious. However I would of thought this will give you an idea of how well the network is performing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nping](http://nmap.org/nping/) can do it. Nping is part of [nmap](http://nmap.org/). Not just it allows to measure response time, but it also very powerfull network testing tool. And it is free software.

On this screenshot you can see `Host is up (0.032s latency)`.

[Zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/) is a GUI for this program.

[image: Zenmap screenshot]

**EDIT:** [tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/) running on modern hardware and OS should allow you to see the timing of the network traffic with the precision down to nanoseconds.

Check out the tcpdump's [FAQ](https://www.tcpdump.org/faq.html) for additional info.

You would need to start the tcpdump first and then ping the host. After this, review the dump of the network traffic produced by the tcpdump to see the timing data.

Comment: OP asked for a tool to make microsecond measurements.

Comment: @Magnus, Thank you for pointing out. I edited the answer to address this point.